# Tasks in database with multiple programs processing them - how to ensure each one is processed exactly once?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Given:

1. I have a database with a table full of tasks.
2. I have a program that processes these tasks. The database is abstracted using NHibernate.
3. The program is run multiple times.

Now, I want to make sure that each task is processed by exactly one process.

One possibility is described [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/76412/18049) but I fail to see how I could transfer this to domain objects mapped to the database with NHibernate.

So, the question is:
How to implement a task processing system with a central data store and multiple concurrent processes that is not accessed directly but through NHibernate?

Comment: Perhaps you need to add some table where you will point that some task is busy by some process.

Comment: How would that work? Assume process one requests a list of all tasks that are not processed. Before process one can mark one of the tasks as being processed, task two also requests a list of all unprocessed tasks. Both processes will get the same list.

Comment: `update TaskList set ownerPID = @PID where taskID = @ID and ownerPID = null`. `Select @@rowcount`.  IF `@@rowcount = 0` then someone else already took the task (ownerPID was non-zero). So try again with the next one.

Comment: @Ben: My question was specifically about NHibernate. Your answer is basically the same approach as the one described in the answer I linked to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Possible Solution 1

One thing that we do is to create a centralized process that hands out work.  We currently have a Wcf service that runs in `InstanceContextMode.Single` ... a singleton service basically.

When the work has been assigned it will update it in the database to reflect that it has been assigned with the requestor's id or just a value that says it's assigned if you don't care about who's getting it.

#### Possible Solution 2

You could use optimistic concurrency in NHibernate on this table that stores the tasks. You would need a column to show that it has been assigned. You would only look for tasks in this table that haven't been assigned. If you go to update the task in the database and someone has already grabbed this task and updated it, you will get a StaleObjectException on the update.

I've never used optimistic concurrency in NHibernate but it seems like that solution could work.  I'm not so sure though that certain processes wouldn't get starved for work and I think you would have to reinitialize your session when that object is thrown.

In my opinion option 1 or something similar to that model works the best.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I like solution 2 better, because I already have a central element (the database), I don't want another one. About reinitializing the session: That's not a problem, my sessions are usually extremely short lived.

Comment: Is solution 2 not very wasteful?

Comment: @csetzkorn What do you mean by wasteful?

Comment: If someone has already grabbed a task and updated it, the 'worker' which gets the StaleObjectException wasted time by doing performing the task as well ...

Comment: @csetzkorn yeah that's why i suggested solution 1 over solution 2

Comment: Agree, just wondered why Daniel picked 2. I am currently trying to implement solution one. I believe marking the service contract with [ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)] should do the trick? This makes the wcf service a wrapper around the database to prevent several workers receiving the same tasks.